# Colouring electrical wire

Tags: substitute-tool, cables

I have recently been working with a string of RGB LEDs to use as Christmas tree lights.

Unfortunately, the lights are supplied with 3 colours of wire, Red, White and Green. To use them on a Christmas tree, I want the wires to be a more appropriate colour. The Green is fine, I figure if I can colour the Red and White with green colourant of some type, the White will become Green and the Red will be Brown/Black.

I want a paint/ink/stain that will work properly on the wire, i.e. remain flexible, not rub off and not be water soluble. There is a lot of wire to colour so I hope to be able to use a sponge to just wipe it on.

What can I use to colour it which fits my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the electrical light sockets also colored? If they're then I would guess they would be made of a different material than the wire insulation. So the dye may work for one and not the other. I don't think wire insulation can be dyed but I cold be wrong.

Honesty I would consider plasti-dip.  Comes in a dip type or spray on. It's flexible and you can buy it in various colors. It's thicker than a coat of dye or paint so the color you pick will not change based on the wires original color.

Have you considered wrapping the wire in colored tape. This could get pricey but it's a simple solution.

One last option is to buy wire loom in large quantities. This is relatively cheap compared to other suggestions and it can be bought in many colors. The split in the loom will be enough to pull each light out.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1, I will definitely look into Plasti-dip some more. It seems to have all the properties I'm looking for - albeit somewhat more messy and expensive than I was hoping.The lamp holders themselves ARE a different material - but I was intending to just wrap them in green insulating tape. If I go with plasti-dip, I will use it on the holders too.  I think coloured tape on the wire will make it too stiff and will take too much effort.  The wire loom idea is a good one too, I didn't know it existed. Thanks!